# How to connect Existing JMS configured as JNDI in JBOSS EAP 7 from spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot

I am having a spring boot application which has to connect to an existing JMS configured as JNDI in JBOSS eap 7. Here is my code:

```
private static final String INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY = "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory";
private static final String CONNECTION_FACTORY = "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory";


@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Retrieving JMS queue with JNDI name: " + CONNECTION_FACTORY);
        JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName(CONNECTION_FACTORY);
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiEnvironment(getEnvProperties());
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

        return (QueueConnectionFactory) jndiObjectFactoryBean.getObject();

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        System.out.println("Error while retrieving JMS queue with JNDI name: [" + CONNECTION_FACTORY + "]");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

Properties getEnvProperties() {
    Properties env = new Properties();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://<<servername>>:8080");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "user");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
    return env;
}

@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    JndiDestinationResolver jndiDestinationResolver = new JndiDestinationResolver();
    jndiDestinationResolver.setJndiEnvironment(getEnvProperties());
    factory.setDestinationResolver(jndiDestinationResolver);
    return factory;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
"javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to any server. Servers tried: [http-remoting://<<servername>>:8080 (java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information)]"
```

Comment: Is your application running as WAR file in JBoss?

Comment: yes its deployed as war file

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create the configuration manually.

Spring Boot supports JNDI.

You can use the ConnectionFactory like this:

```
spring.jms.jndi-name=java:/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
```

Please also have a look at the documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jms-jndi

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the above and now i am getting below error. Any help you can throw on this please.

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'connectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jndi.TypeMismatchNamingException: Object of type [class org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory] available at JNDI location [java:/ConnectionFactory] is not assignable to [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory]

Comment: So you are using Artemis in JBoss EAP 7? How does the configuration of RemoteConnectionFactory in the standalone.xml look like?

Comment: Please find below subsytem module added in Jboss.Let me know if i doing any setting wrong.
         <jms-queue name="POQueue" entries="java:/jms/POQueue"/>
                <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
                <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
                <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" transaction="xa" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>

Comment: I am not using artemis in jboss. But springboot auto configuration is always expecting to type cast. I tried different combination of connection factory in Jboss and added it in jndi-name in properties file. But every time it gives me the typemismatch error. Please help on this.

Comment: Without JNDI sprintboot and activemq works fine in my code setup